# If you've already been infected with SARS-CoV-2, do the vaccines cause fewer side effects?

Tags: covid-19, vaccination, side-effects, sars-cov-2, vaccine

Assuming that I had Covid-19 not so long ago. My body should have produced some type of antibodies to defend against the infection*. If I now get one of the vaccines, would it be more likely that possible side effects are less intense because my body is better prepared?

a) for mRNA vaccines
b) for a traditional vaccine

Hope that the question makes sense for you.

I know some biology-basics but nothing more.

*I know that there are mutations of the virus, so that the antibodies my body produced (more accurate: remembers how to build ) could not be sufficient to prevent an infection from a mutation like the delta-variant

EDIT :

Sorry, I haven't researched well enough. I just thought about it and then spontaneously asked the question. I was hoping for a brief summary of the different opinions on this issue. I don't have time to do any deeper research, but my impression is that more research is needed to answer my question. Some data seem to suggest that some mild side effects of the first dose of vaccine are more common for people who have already had Covid-19.

Example: https://www.gavi.org/vaccineswork/why-vaccine-side-effects-might-be-more-common-people-whove-already-had-covid-19

PS:
English is not my native language, please correct me if I made mistakes.

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. So have you attempted to find the answer to this question? What did you find? And if you found nothing, what did you search for?

Comment: A good thing to research would be "what causes the side effects"?